# could not find function "unnest_tokens"

Tags: r, tidytext, unnest

I'm trying to split a column into tokens using the tokenizers package but I keep receiving an error: could not find function "unnest_tokens". I am using R 3.5.3 and have installed and reinstalled dplyr, tidytext, tidyverse, tokenizers, tidyr, but still keep receiving the error.

I have also quit and restarted R and RStudio.

```
comments_tidy <- comments %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, txt) %>% #Break the comments into individual words
  filter(!word %in% undesirable_words) %>% #Remove undesirables
  anti_join(stop_words) #Data provided by the tidytext package
```

I receive the following:

> Error in unnest_tokens(., word, txt) :
>   could not find function "unnest_tokens"

Comment: Did you call `library(x)`;`library(y)`?

Comment: Yes, I called each library for the packages mentioned in the description.

Comment: Try being explicit: `tidytext::unnest_tokens()`

Comment: Thanks! The explicit function helped me too.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you may want to expand your code with `library(x)` statements. In addition, make sure that all the packages **and their dependencies** are installed. The following snippet would look up a given package (in this case `dplyr`) and install it if needed.

```
if ("dplyr" %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"]){ 
  cat("'dplyr' is installed.")
} else {
  install.packages("dplyr",dependencies=T)
}
library(dplyr)
```

The command `installed.packages()[, "Package"])?` gives you a list of all installed packages, that is a nice trick for debugging all kind of `Function foo not found` errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to run this first

```
install.packages("tidytext")
library(tidytext)
```

You only need to run the first line once - it will install the package.

You need to run the second line in each new R session, since that will load the package.

Answer (score -2):

Calling library (tidytext) and `tidytext::unnest_tokens()` solved the problem for me.